# Why would a shortcut point to a network share and back?

Tags: network-share, windows

I stumbled across something that caught my interest the other day: two Windows servers where one contains a shortcut `\\SERVER1\C\MyFolder` that points to `\\SERVER2\SHARES\MyFolder` and that's a share that points to `\\SERVER1\C\MyFolder`...

- How does this not cause a circular reference or dependency that would cause network overhead? (Fatal Cucumber Error. Please Reboot Universe or something along those lines...)
- What are situations where this would be "a good idea" from a server admin perspective and why?

FYI: yes this is a real situation in a real (and very large) company.

Answer (score 1):

It works like redirection of userdata and would be useful if you were dealing with an environment where data might move in the future while a piece of software might require a static reference- for example in a program where files might be referenced in so the program needs a static reference point, and perhaps is a situation where file access needs change by project.

Doe a favor- give me 10 more minutes before rebooting the universe- I need to save some changes .